# SQL CONVERT and FLOOR query

Tags: sql, t-sql, floor

What is the difference between these two queries? Why do they give different results?

**Query 1**

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar
SET @test = CONVERT(nvarchar, FLOOR(10.5))
SELECT @test
```

Results:

```
['1']
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, FLOOR(10.5))
```

Results:

```
['10']
```

Comment: Which is the result that you expected/wanted?

Comment: The second (10). @Alex's answer was right though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar
```

That's 1 character long so truncates its assigned value; add a (size)